# Saving image file into the database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

how can i save the file using c# into the SQL server dataqbase after user has selected the file location using fileupload control in asp.net .

Comment: are you sure you want to store these images into database? because it consume a lot of space ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImageSaveInDataBase.aspx

Comment: http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server/105-store-save-images-in-sql-server.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Saving an Image into DB ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806159/c-saving-an-image-into-db)

Comment: i have already seen that.but i didnt get a good answer there

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
if (this.fileUploader.PostedFile == null ||
    this.fileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength < 1)
{
   this.LabelError.Text = this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "NoFileToUpload")
                              .ToString();
   return;
}

MyTableWithImageField i = new MyTableWithImageField();

i.ImageData = this.fileUploader.FileBytes;

command.CommandText = @"InsertMyTableWithImageField";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", i.ImageData);
```

You may also want to check this from MSDN: [Uploading Files in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)